Easiest way to GRANT SHOWPLAN in Azure SQL
So not an expert on Azure Portal, I mostly still connect with SSMS to these resources using EntraID etc. I have a need to grant a single user SHOWPLAN perms on a single database. When I look under the Security folder though their user is not listed there. I have poked around in the Portal and found their user (name.name@blahblah.net) but no way to add this single permission to them. I could add it to an Azure group they belong to but that is not visible in SSMS either. Everything I have found seems to suggest I have to add them as dbowner and I really don't want to do that.
Do I have to create a special Role in Azure or something and if so how best to do that?

"Everything I have found seems to suggest I have to add them as dbowner" - Yea, don't do that. That's wrong and bad. How does that user have access to the database?...directly or with an Azure Group?

Instead of trying to use Azure Portal security folder or SSMS GUI to assign that permission to view execution plans of queries, try below Transact-SQL statement:
GRANT SHOWPLAN TO [YourUserName];

Here you will find a similar forum thread on Microsoft QA.

wouldn't you need also ssms or some similar software to run the sql code?

You can use Query Editor on Azure Portal from a Web Browser while using a tablet. No need to install SSMS, Azure Data Studio, etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-portal?view=azuresql
